# openerp inherit from report_account_common

Tags: inheritance, openerp-7

I'm creating a jasper report for balance sheet and I saw that the following file:
"addons\account\report\account_financial_report.py" has a method that gets all information needed for my report, so I want to create a module that can get that method (get_lines) and can generate my new report from that values.

Is it possible? that file has the following:

```
class report_account_common(report_sxw.rml_parse, common_report_header):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(report_account_common, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update( {
            'get_lines': self.get_lines,
            'time': time,
            'get_fiscalyear': self._get_fiscalyear,
            'get_account': self._get_account,
            'get_start_period': self.get_start_period,
            'get_end_period': self.get_end_period,
            'get_filter': self._get_filter,
            'get_start_date':self._get_start_date,
            'get_end_date':self._get_end_date,
            'get_target_move': self._get_target_move,
        })
        self.context = context

    def set_context(self, objects, data, ids, report_type=None):
        new_ids = ids
        if (data['model'] == 'ir.ui.menu'):
            new_ids = 'chart_account_id' in data['form'] and [data['form']['chart_account_id']] or []
            objects = self.pool.get('account.account').browse(self.cr, self.uid, new_ids)
        return super(report_account_common, self).set_context(objects, data, new_ids, report_type=report_type)

    def get_lines(self, data):
        lines = []
        account_obj = self.pool.get('account.account')
         ..... more code ......
```

So I want to call to get_lines method and work with the value returned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from account_financial_report and then call the function:

```
def yourFunction(data):

--- your code----

return super(account_financial_report, self).get_lines(data)
```

call your function to get the values where you need it.